# Any free or low cost bug trackers in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, bug-tracking

Does anyone know of any free or low cost bug/issue trackers in Silverlight?

Comment: whats with the silverlight constraint?

Comment: I was wondering. What is with the other similar questions with the .Net constraint?

Comment: .net is significantly broader in scope than silverlight.  i would be able to assume the op was using .net because they're developing for a windows environment.  silverlight, however, has no obvious use case for a bug tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's always [Telerik's Bug Tracker demo application](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/BugTracker/). :)